# How to use "curl -Is link | head -n 1" with many links in a file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, sh

i want to use this `curl -Is link | head -n 1` to check if a link is alive ,but this is for one link ,anyone help me to check with a large number link in a file ,i has tried `curl -Is Mylink.txt | head -n 1`  ,but it does not achieve my goal .Thanks for any help .

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your lines are well formatted (as `curl` likely needs them to be anyway) @codeforester's should work for you.  As a matter of habit I try to avoid using `cat` and `for` loops to parse files though so I'd do it a little differently:

```
while read -r line; do
    printf 'URL %s: %s\n' "$line" "$(curl -Is "$line" | head -n 1)"
done < Mylink.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for xargs! Depending on what your file looks like that is. I'm assuming there is one link per line. Why are you using the -Is? Especially the -s for silent mode if you want to see errors? You may actually want the -s -S options together ([link](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-s))

```
xargs < links.txt -I % sh -c 'curl -Is "$1" | head -n1' _ %
```

edited to reflect corrections in the comments, thanks!

Comment: `head -n1` filters the entire output of `xargs`, not each call to `curl` individually.

Comment: You should avoid constructs such as `cat foo.txt | bar` when possible, and instead do `bar < foo.txt`. In this case, the correct code would be `xargs < links.txt -I % sh -c "curl -Is % | head -n1"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for link in $(cat Mylink.txt)
do
    echo $link: $(curl -Is $link | head -n 1)
done
```

Comment: Please read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over a file.